# Каталог товаров

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Передо мной стоит задача: создать каталог товаров. На главной странице 2 кнопки: телефоны и аксессуары. При нажатии на кнопку телефоны открывается список телефонов, где есть картинка телефона, название и цена. При нажатии на кнопку аксессуары происходит примерно тоже самое только с аксессуарами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать. У меня 2 вопроса:

1. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалась новая пустая форма?
2. Как реализовать, чтобы в новой форме был список товаров как в приложении яндекс маркет.

Какой элемент формы использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Проще всего через `UINavigationController`, в xcode есть соответствующий шаблон, чтобы открыть новый вид, в обработчике кнопки создаете его контроллер (далее vc) и делаете `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`. Все, он сам попадет на экран.
2. В Я.Маркете это `UITableView` с кастомными ячейками, нужно создать класс-наследник от `UITableViewCell` и дописать ему недостающие поля.

Comment: Что вы подрузумеваете (далее vc)?
Что в квадратных скобках тоже в обработчик кнопки записывать?

Comment: что я переменную котороллера обозвал vc, ничего больше.

Answer (score 2):

Как, да очень просто, кидаем в интерфейс билдере две кнопки на вью, прикрепляем к ним действие(IBAction) тоесть, дальше добавляем в проект два UIViewController'a или два класса  UIView, в них точим таблицы или поля для ввода текста и так далее, берем яндекс апи парсим его и отображаем все красиво как надо.

Comment: И всё же что лучше использовать UINavigationController или UIViewController???

Comment: Если можете,приведите пожста пример реализации,хотя бы одной кнопки.

Comment: UINavigationController  удобнее если много переходить, например в том же маркете от категорий переходим к списку товаров, далее на описание конкретного товара, далее можем на список магазинов ну и т.п., ну а способ x86-64 более прост если у вас нет такой сложной навигации

Comment: Я думаю мне подходит UINavigationController. Помогите пожста его реализовать на одной кнопке.

Comment: Ну если Вы решили заюзать UINavigationController, то вы не завяжете его на одной кнопке, UINavigationController необходимо создать в AppDelegate а дальше привязывать действие к UIBarButtonItem уже в вашем ViewController'e. Здесь находится руководство как использовать UINavigationController http://www.uinnoblog.com/uinavigationcontroller-programmatically.html